# JSON PHP array from Objective C

Tags: php, json, object

`$arrayOfEmails=$_POST["arrayOfEmails"];`

1st question: `$arrayOfEmails` is now just an array in JSON notation. How would I convert this to a PHP array?

`$arrayOfDictionaries=...`

//after querying the db, this gets assigned a JSON string, which was originally an objective c array of dictionaries. So after it's converted to a PHP array,

`$dictionaryToBeAdded=$_POST["dictionary"];`

The above is now only a non-decoded JSON string, originally an Objective C dictionary, then converted.

2nd question: I need to convert this dictionary to PHP and then add it to the `arrayOfDictionaries` above. How could I do this?

(I'm not very familiar with PHP syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1, Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode).

For #2, just do $arrayOfDictionaries[] = [whatever your new row is]. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: So for #2, `$arrayOfDictionaries[]=$dictionaryToBeAdded` would insert `dictionaryToBeAdded` to my `arrayOfDictionaries`?

Comment: Yes. In that case, the index will be 0, 1, 2, etc. If you do $arrayOfDictionaries['my_key_name'] you can create an associative array instead.